# line breaks using javascript strings

Tags: javascript, string, line-breaks

I m breaking a line in javascript using \n for example: -

text = "this is a test" + "\n" + "another test";

and to show that in html i m using the code

```
text = text.replace('\n' , '<br>');
```

but the text i m getting is without the br

when checking in firebug console i get is with line break(\n not shown but newline created)

how can i place line breaks using \n or i have to do some custom code instead of \n

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var newText = text.replace(/\n/g , "<br>");
```

Comment: O O thanks.. regex.. somethings cannot be done without regex..:D

Comment: can u please take a look at this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558136/simplfy-javascript-code-using-regex

Comment: @Pradyut - It can be done with-out regex using a loop, regex is just easier.

Comment: ya i m using a loop for getting the urls one by one for checking... that can be done with regex..thats wat the question is about simplying using regex...please help...

Answer (score 3):

use double quotes to not escape the \n

try this:

```
text = text.replace("\n" , "<br>");
```

Answer (score 3):

/\r\n|[\r\n]/g <- this is what I use. I am a pessimist..