# simplify javascript code using regex (getting multiple links to iframes youtube)

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi
I have a code which can show youtube videos if there are any links to youtube in the text

like for example the text which has **multiple links**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LiPMxFBLZY
testing
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3-l22b_Qg8&feature=related

example at:- [pradyut.dyndns.org](http://pradyut.dyndns.org)

the question has three parts which can be done using regex..

1 > **getting the urls one by one for checking**

2>checking if they youtube urls

3>converting the urls to youtube objects or iframes...

the second and the third are almost done with regex .. any improvements are welcome...

the most **cumbersome is part one** of the code which is to be done using regex...

this text i m forwarding to the function...

```
   function to_youtubelink(text)
            {
                if ( text.indexOf ('<') > 0 || text.indexOf ('"') > 0 || text.indexOf ('>') > 0 )
                    return text;
                else
                {
                    var obj_text = new Array();
                    var oi = 0;
                    while(text.indexOf('http://') >=0)
                    { //getting the paths
                        var si = text.indexOf('http://');
                        var gr = text.indexOf('\n', si);
                        var sp = text.indexOf(' ', si);
                        var ei;
                        if ( gr > 0 || sp > 0  )
                        {
                            if ( gr >0 && sp > 0 )
                            {
                                if ( gr < sp )
                                {
                                    ei = gr ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ei = sp ;
                                }
                            }
                            else if ( gr > 0)
                            {
                                ei = gr;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ei = sp;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ei = text.length;
                        }
                        var it = text.substring(si,ei);

                        if ( it.indexOf('"') > 0)
                        {
                            it.substring(0, it.indexOf('"') );
                        }

                        if(ei < 0)
                            ei = text.length;
                        else
                            ei = text.indexOf(' ', si) ;

                        obj_text[oi] = it;

                        text = text.replace( it, '[link_service]');
                        oi++;

                    }

                    var ob_text = new Array();
                    var ob =0;
                    for (oi=0; oi<obj_text.length; oi++)
                    {
                        if ( is_youtubelink( obj_text[oi] ) )
                        {
                            ob_text[ob] = to_utubelink(obj_text[oi]);

                            ob++;
                        }
                    }
                    oi = 0;
                    while ( text.indexOf('[link_service]') >=0  )
                    {

                        text = text.replace( '[link_service]', obj_text[oi]);

                        oi ++;
                    }

                    for (ob=0; ob<ob_text.length; ob++)
                    {
                        text = text +"\n\n" + ob_text[ob];
                    }

                    return text;
                }
            }

       function is_youtubelink(text)
            {
                var matches = text.match(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.*watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);
                if (matches) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }

            function to_utubelink(text)
            {
                var video_id = text.split('v=')[1];
                    var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
                    if(ampersandPosition != -1)
                    {
                        video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
                    }

                    text = "<iframe title=\"YouTube video player\" class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"425\" height=\"350\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id + "\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"
                    return text;
            }
```

now i m getting the output properly...

but i was thinking if the code could be done better and simplified using regex

...especially getting the urls part...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
/**
 * Extracts a youtube id from a string
 * 
 * @param string
 *
 * @return mixed
 */

function youtubeIDextract(text) { 
    var replace = "$1";

    if (!text.match(/http:\/\/www\.youtube[^"]+/))
        return false;

    if (text.match(/^[^v]+v.([^&^=^\/]{11}).*/))
        return text.replace(/^[^v]+v.([^&^=^\/]{11}).*/,replace); 
    else if (text.match(/^[^v]+\?v=([^&^=^\/]{11}).*/))
        return text.replace(/^[^v]+\?v=([^&^=^\/]{11}).*/,replace); 
    else
        return false;
}
```

A working example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/6PRVp/2/

If you want to simply check if there is a youtube link in there somewhere, do this:

```
if (youtubeIDextract(text)) {...}
```

Notice that this also checks if there are 11 characters in the video id (without that, it would be a malformed youtube link).

Comment: i m already doing this in the function "to_utubelink"(the last function od my code).. may this is a better implmentation...

Comment: @Pradyut: hold on, tweaking it now.

Comment: i dont know much about regex although but take a look for matching if the url is from youtube with a wider regex in my function "is_youtubelink()"... thanks...

Comment: in the link there u r having only one youtube link... put a run with my text with multiple youtube links...no hurry btw:D

Comment: @Pradyut: hm yes, it appears to not match all cases. I'm trying to figure this out at the moment.

Comment: the part one of the question is getting the urls one by one for checking... that is first to be done.. then the urls are to be sent to your function "youtubeIDextract" and then to wrap the id in object or iframe...

Comment: @Pradyut: sorry I can't figure this out any further (not enough time). This is as far as I got: http://jsfiddle.net/6PRVp/4/

Comment: O:O: thanks for your time... you are close enough... please try again sometime later...and please refer the question to js guys too...:D

Comment: @Pradyut the biggest reason why you didn't get many hits on this question is because it looks monolithic. Try to pare the problem down into a single issue instead of just pasting a giant piece of code and saying "improve it". I've left you at a place where all you need to figure out is how to get this regex `/^.*(http:\/\/www\.youtube[\S]+)[\s]*.*?/g` to match each instance. Start a new question and ask it there. Describe exactly that you want to match every occurrence of a youtube link, but this regex matches too much.

Comment: @Pradyut: it's also important to note that my regexes for matching the video ids DO work. Once you get the link regex working, you can run those on each link to get an array of urls and video ids. From that, you can very easily construct an iframe or embed object.

Comment: thanks treeface... ok now one simple question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560791/parse-text-with-multiple-links-using-regex-in-javascript

Comment: @Pradyut: nicely done! See I told you...you can find an answer to any question on StackOverflow...if you ask the right questions. :-]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function to_youtubelink(a) {
if (a.indexOf("<") > 0 || a.indexOf('"') > 0 || a.indexOf(">") > 0) return a;
var b = Array(),
    c = 0;
while (a.indexOf("http://") >= 0) {
    var g, d = a.indexOf("http://"),
        e = a.indexOf("\n", d),
        f = a.indexOf(" ", d);
    g = e > 0 || f > 0 ? e > 0 && f > 0 ? f > e ? e : f : e > 0 ? e : f : a.length;
    var h = a.substring(d, g);
    h.indexOf('"') > 0 && h.substring(0, h.indexOf('"')), g = 0 > g ? a.length : a.indexOf(" ", d), b[c] = h, a = a.replace(h, "[link_service]"), c++
}
var i = Array(),
    j = 0;
for (c = 0; b.length > c; c++) is_youtubelink(b[c]) && (i[j] = to_utubelink(b[c]), j++);
c = 0;
while (a.indexOf("[link_service]") >= 0) a = a.replace("[link_service]", b[c]), c++;
for (j = 0; i.length > j; j++) a = a + "\n\n" + i[j];
return a
}
function is_youtubelink(a) {
var b = a.match(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.*watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);
return b ? !0 : !1
}
function to_utubelink(a) {
var b = a.split("v=")[1],
    c = b.indexOf("&");
return c != -1 && (b = b.substring(0, c)), a = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="425" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + b + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
}
```