# parse text with multiple links using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi
i m having a text having multiple links wrapped inside text...

i want a regex(i m using javascript) which can parse the text and return a array of the links...

for example for the text...

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LiPMxFBLZY
testing
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3-l22b_Qg8&feature=related
```

the regex would parse the text and return a array of the links

```
arr[0] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LiPMxFBLZY"
arr[1] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3-l22b_Qg8&feature=related"
```

i m trying to do so with the code...

```
var ytre =/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig ;
var matches = new Array();

                    matches = ytre.exec(text);
                    var jm;
                    if (matches !=null )
                    {
                        for (jm=0; jm<matches.length; jm++)
                        {
                            console.log(matches[jm]);
                        }
                    }
```

but its not returning the appropriate results...

please help

thanks

Comment: library which does this: http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/ (see http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#static-withinString)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
var text = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LiPMxFBLZY testing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3-l22b_Qg8&feature=related http://yahoo.com';

var ytre = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

var resultArray = text.match(ytre);
```

[**See it**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/3UeQY/1/)

Comment: :O thanks.. really new to regex... now if i have to check it *only* for youtube links...http://www.jsfiddle.net/WWmvT/2/

Comment: You can do:http://www.jsfiddle.net/WWmvT/4/ you can also make the http:// and the www. part optional.

Comment: anything which checks watch?v=-LiPMxFBLZY in the link like in this regex... /http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.*watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/

Answer (score 6):

To parse URLs, using regexs, look at the RFC that defines URLs.

So to find regular expressions, use a variant that makes the protocol and authority non-optional, like `/\b(([^:\/?#]+):)(\/\/([^\/?#]*))([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/gi`.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt says

> Appendix B.  Parsing a URI Reference
>   with a Regular Expression
>
> As the "first-match-wins" algorithm
>   is identical to the "greedy"
>   disambiguation method used by POSIX
>   regular expressions, it is    natural
>   and commonplace to use a regular
>   expression for parsing the
>   potential five components of a URI
>   reference.
>
> The following line is the regular
>   expression for breaking-down a
>   well-formed URI reference into its
>   components.
>
> ```
>   ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>    12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```
>
> The numbers in the second line
>   above are only to assist readability; 
>   they indicate the reference points for
>   each subexpression (i.e., each
>   paired parenthesis).  We refer to the
>   value matched for subexpression    
>   as $.  For example, matching the
>   above expression to
>
> ```
>   http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
> ```
>
> results in the following
>   subexpression matches:
>
> ```
>   $1 = http:
>   $2 = http
>   $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
>   $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
>   $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
>   $6 = <undefined>
>   $7 = <undefined>
>   $8 = #Related
>   $9 = Related
> ```
>
> where  indicates that
>   the component is not present, as is
>   the case for the query component in
>   the above example.  Therefore, we
>   can determine the value of the five
>   components as
>
> ```
>   scheme    = $2
>   authority = $4
>   path      = $5
>   query     = $7
>   fragment  = $9
> ```