# Angular.js directive template: break line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, templates, angularjs-directive

Assuming I have this demo directive:

```
app.directive('name', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-class="done" ng-click="doSomething(data.done, index)">{{data.text}}<button ng-click="remove(index)">delete</button></div>'  
    }
});
```

Is it ok just to break the string for the template, or should I add "+" or something in the end of each line? 
e.g. -

```
app.directive('name', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-class="done" ng-click="doSomething(data.done, index)">
                       {{data.text}}
                       <button ng-click="remove(index)">delete</button>
                   </div>'
    }
});
```

Thank you :)

Comment: have you considered using templateUrl and putting your html inside of an .html file?

Comment: Well it's really simple in my case, so no. Just thought about this scenario in general :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't break lines in single quotes without getting an error. You can use double quotes, but that's not recommended in strict JavaScript mode. Probably best to use one string per line with a + at the end, creating the result

Notes on double quotes:
[line breaks using javascript strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558008/line-breaks-using-javascript-strings)

It's probably better to use a templateUrl if the template is going to get more complicated.